# Template argument calculations

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor

(NOTE: Working on a GCC 4.6 with no C++0x flags, external restriction. I am also interested on what would happen with C++11 and/or more recent compilers)

I have a templated class for operating on matrices of fixed size:

```
template<size_t rows, size_t cols, class Type>
class MatrixFixed;
```

In that class, I have defined a "shift" operation that has the following aspect:

```
template<size_t rows, size_t cols, class Type>
template<size_t numRowsUp>
MatrixLogicalFixed<rows,cols,Type> MatrixLogicalFixed<rows,cols,Type>::shiftUp( const Type & filler ) const
{
    if( (numRowsUp>=rows) )
    {
        return MatrixLogicalFixed<rows,cols,Type>(filler);
    }
    else
    {
        MatrixLogicalFixed<numRowsUp,cols,Type> temp(filler);
        return this->getSubMatrix<rows-numRowsUp,cols>( numRowsUp, 0 )
                    .joinV( temp );
    }
}
```

The idea is that, if the number of positions to shift is larger than the total number of rows, a matrix filled with the default value can be returned.
However, in those cases (`numRowsUp >= rows`) the compilation ends with an **internal compiler error: in force_constant_size at gimplify.c:691** at the last code line `.joinV( temp )`

Matrix sizes during the process (my guess):

- Returned value: (rows x cols) matrix
- `getSubMatrix<rows-numRowsUp,cols>( numRowsUp, 0 )`: when `numRowsUp>=rows`, this will result in a huge number due to size_t underflow
- `joinV` function tries to deduce the appropriate return size, but this is impossible.

This is joinV declaration):

```
template<size_t rows, size_t cols, class Type>
template<size_t rows2, size_t cols2>
MatrixLogicalFixed<rows+rows2,cols,Type> MatrixLogicalFixed<rows,cols,Type>::joinV(const MatrixLogicalFixed<rows2,cols2,Type> & B) const
```

Since the `if` condition is defined **at compile time**, this is a piece of code that will **NEVER** be reached in the problematic case. What I have tried so far:

- Use template parameters in preprocessor #if --obviously wrong.
- Look for any kind of preprocessor macro MIN or MAX that can do the trick.

Usual partial specialization doesn't look like a valid workaround, since there are infinite combinations of values... I am open to any kind of solution. I just want my class to compile :D

Comment: Have you tried a more recent compiler version?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry... I forgot to mention that we are restricted to gcc 4.6 with no c++0x flags :P

Comment: I'd forward to a partial specialization on an additional boolean parameter which would get `numRowsUp>=rows` as value.

Comment: I will try it ASAP :D

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with preprocessor MAX?
You can use `MAX(0, rows-numRowsUp)` as template argument. Or try this as template argument: `(numRowsUp>=rows)? 0 : rows-numRowsUp`. This way wrong template will never be instaniated.

Comment: What the... I would swear I tried this and the compiler yelled at me. Is there any requirement so that the correct MAX is used?